# CSS Media Query for Language translation is not responding on wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries, translation

Hello Everyone i have an issue, i'm working on website with two different languages. main language is arabic and secondary is English, i have prepared everything and it's fine but when i change from arabic to english a lot of styles get courrepted so in order to fix this i use media query for languages i usued This code and it worked fine untill i pressed a wrong button the directed me to other without saving it should be big deal since i write my code first in VScode editor firsit then i paste it again and when i did so my code didn't work at all i tried changing browser and changing a lot of ways of writing it but still no respnse for anything has to do with :lang(en)

first of all my worpdress page got HTML attribute lang="en-US"
and these are the codes i have tried and it worked fine in the first place

```
@media screen and (max-width:1980px) {
  #header-resp-two h1:lang(en) {
    font-size: 55px !important;
    font-family: sans-serif !important;
  }

  #testomonial-main-image:lang(en) {
    text-align: right !important;
  }

  .testomonial:lang(en) {
    left: -7%;
  }

  .testomonial-size-two h1:lang(en) {
    font-size: 26px !important;
    font-family: sans-serif !important;
  }

  .testomonial-size-two p:lang(en) {
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

also i have tried this

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1650px) {
:lang(en) #header-resp-two h1 {
  font-size: 55px !important;
  font-family: sans-serif !important;
 }
}
```

i used developper tools to findout what is wrong but i cant find my code
and tried other browser
and tried to remvoe the code and type it again and again and still nothing
tried to use other specifity and still can't find it

Answer (score 0):

Please try with

```
html[lang="en"] #header-resp-two h1{
  font-size: 55px !important;
  font-family: sans-serif !important;
}
```

I hope it work!

Comment: I Tried it but sadly didn't workout i think the problem might be with the Lang selecting like if it's not visible i don't know  how this could even happen but i can't find a reason for not showing up my code at all  not with to mention that it was working in the first place and nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

Hello Guys and thanks for the assist the problem turned out in wordpress plugin it's kinda weird but it i've tired other plugin and it worked

Answer (score -1):

maybe little bit later, but this works for me

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
    html:lang(ka) .arcdesign {
    font-family: "avaza_mtavruli" !important;
    text-transform: none;
    font-size: 11px !important;
    }
}
```

Also, if for ID selector still not working, try CLASS selector.

Regards